# Sudden "organic" traffic growing after AdWords campaign starting

Tags: seo, google-analytics, traffic, google-ads, web-traffic

**The situation:**
My site had no organic traffic from Google. It has some referral traffic.
After I have launched adwords, my "organic" traffic increased, but not "paid" and no money has been spent in adwords.
AdWords and Google Analytics accounts are connected.

**The issue:**
What is the reason of sudden "organic" traffic growing? Is it due to AdWords launching?

**UPDATE:**
Users visit my site by ordinary keywords and not by the site domain name. And they are all new visitiors.

**UPDATE 2:**
Site URL is `www.sitefeedbacks.com`
The site is not bound to any event. Its just day-to-day basis site similar to forum.

**UPDATE 3:**
I have used Adwords in the past for this site on another AdWords account.

**UPDATE 4:**
I have just found an issue. It was another Google Adwords campaign on another account.
My stupid mistake.

Only one question has no answer: Why did Google Analytics attribute that traffic to "organic", but not to "paid"?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your Adwords link going to sitefeedbacks.com rather than www.sitefeedbacks.com? A 301 redirect here would lose the tracking parameter.

Comment: My Adwords link going directly to www.sitefeedbacks.com

Comment: I think it's because Paid traffic comes when a user click on an ad to come to your website, and organic is when it's via keywords, so if you configured your keywords using the `adwords keyword tool` it could be extremely helpful

Comment: @knif3r I'm not sure I understood you well.

Comment: I tried to say that the traffic which enters in the `paid traffic` chart is from people who've clicked on your ads in websites who use adsence, and the chart using the data form `organic traffic` comes from google search, other sites, other search engines and etc.. About the tool, when you start a campaign in adwords you get access to their `Google Keywords Tool` which shows you the most used keywords and gives you the chance to modify yours so you can use the most entered keywords in the search query of google, which more or less guarantee traffic.

Comment: @knif3r 1. We have used Seacrh Network ads only.
2. Are you sure about Adsense as organic reporting?

Comment: Indeed Adsence is not organic report, it's paid because you pay for clicks on your ads, since you use only search network ads it is normal to have organic traffic only, if you pick adsence it would be pay per click on your ads which goes to paid reporting,

Comment: What do you mean under "normal"? We have had paid ads on Google search pages. By default they should be reported as paid, not organic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your site was not indexed by Google, and the AdWords campaign led the site to be indexed. Now, a search on Google will find you, where you wouldn't show before?

Or it could be return visitors.  They click on your adwords ad, visit site and want to go back.  But they cant remember the direct link so they search for your name on google and find you that way.

There really is not enough info given to answer the question.  If you sell wimbledon final memorabilia maybe people only look for this and find your site after the final, so there is a spike in taffic only at a certain date. Who, what, why where, when?  Do you want to give more info?

Comment: For the first time my site has been indexed at the beginning of March.

Comment: Jon, I've updated my question. I gave my site's URL and short description.

Comment: yeah I saw the updates.  I ran out of sane ideas.  There are so many inputs into why you got traffic last week.  It reminds me of a joke - A- I went to a maths class and I found out there is a difference between causation and correlation.  B- Sounds like it was a good class.  A - Dont know

Comment: "There are so many inputs into why you got traffic last week."  
That is the reason I have asked this question. It is not standard situation.

Comment: but it might have been a random occurrence nothing to do with adwords.  Adwords will not help your organic rankings

Comment: "Adwords will not help your organic rankings"  
I know it, that is why I have asked it.

Comment: so thats why its probably a random un connected event

Comment: It is very suspicious to be a random (Adwords starting -> Organic traffic growing).

Comment: like I say correlation and causation

Comment: Please, read my Update 4.
Can somebody give me an answer?

Comment: Im just guessing as I dont know or tested, but since you did not pay for these hits, but a separate account paid for it - its deemed as not paid, ergo organic?  But you can test this yourself

Comment: But other ppc-systems appear in Google Analytics as "paid", so why just another Google Adwords account has been tracked as organic?

Comment: "but since you did not pay for these hits" - I had paid for them, but from another Google ADwords account.

Comment: google has customer service.  you can ask them.  They will tell you.  Use the adwords account that was clicked on and say that the clicks come up as organic in analytics. There are too many variables I dont have

Answer (score 0):

> What is the reason of sudden "organic" traffic growing? Is it due to AdWords launching?

AdWords can't influence the organic search performance of your site. Organic search and AdWords are not related.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this on my website also, That's why I have asked this question here.

[Is there any relationship between Adword spending & Google organic SEO position?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/87622/is-there-any-relationship-between-adword-spending-google-organic-seo-position)

So, My ans is "yes".