# Is there any relationship between Adword spending & Google organic SEO position?

Tags: seo, search-results, google-ads, search, ppc

I think, there is a relationship between Adword spending & Google organic SEO position. Google might not do it explicitly or in a deliberate way, But there is in my experience.

For example, Assume two websites A & B are having a same SEO strength and same organic traffic.

Assume few months, we spend more money on promoting website B on Adword, the organic results are improving for the site B, but not for the site A.

This i have seen it many times, Please clarify my views.

Comment: No, there is no relationship. If there were Google would get sued for anti-trust violations.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:** No, there is no direct relation between google adwords spending and organic traffic.

**Long Answer:**

When you spend money on adwords or any other online advertisements, more people will know about your website. Thus, more people will visit, link, share your website which may result in higher organic traffic or higher SEO Rank. Also, more people will then directly search your website on google to comeback.

My point is that if you spend money on bing network, you will still see the growth in google SEO ranking.

Infact, any advertising, through any channel (TV, Print or Online) will result in higher organic traffic and/or higher SEO Rank as more people will know about you and it will reflect in your seo rank.

Comment: I think, your answer is correct. but looking for more information.

Comment: What more information are you looking for? Google don't link the two things up - it won't show you higher in organic results if you spend money on adwords. Why? First, because it will be legally wrong (anti-competition) and secondly, there is no economic reason for google to do this. They are no.1 in advertising because people use their search results and not because they give higher ranking to advertisers. Google need to maintain their search quality if they want to remain market leader. Although, they are now placing more and more ads on search result page but that's a different discussion.

Answer (score 1):

There is no relationship between Adwords spending and organic traffic, which is why one is seen as "paid" (Adwords) and the other "organic" (SEO) - totally separate channels.

However, if people do love and start sharing your product page or other spin off content pages from your website to social networks or blog about it etc. (backlinks), it will no doubt help with your SEO rankings. This could be particularly so if your campaign landing page, ad relevance etc. is highly optimized for conversions. If people buy, they'll most likely talk about it yes?

Answer (score 0):

As hendry pointed,
It's just like any other medium of advertising our brand. 
We will surely get page views and attention from the outside world and Google search.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally seen websites gain traffic and organic ranking from being AdWords advertisers. Google does not claim that AdWords has anything to do with organic, but I've seen the results. It seems to help a lot.

Comment: Can you provide more details?  How large were the sites, how big were the Adsense accounts?   Did you observe SEO traffic go up during big ad buys and go down when spending decreased?  How tight was the correlation?      I'm a bit skeptical about your experience.

Answer (score 0):

So I have been doing some research on this as I saw a correlation between my organic traffic and google adwords traffic. Whenever I increase my adword spend my orgnic traffic increases and vice versa.

Is google doing this deliberately - probably NOT. But its a vicious circle, the more people see your adverts the more they search for you organically so both go in tandem. This is especially true if you are an eCommerce player and most of your business is new business.

I actually went ahead and did some mathematical regression testing! The result for my site showed a 76% correlation between organic and paid traffic. So yea, there definitely is a correlation between the two.